# Hyperlink usage

Tags: php, html

Is it true hyperlinks should never be used to perform actions?

For example, Would it be bad to do this:

```
<a href="?action=doThis" class="btn">do this button</a>
```

Instead of this:

```
<form action="?doThis" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="action" value="doThis">
   <input type="submit" value="do this">
</form>
```

Both works, but are both correct?

Update

I took the reference in a book i'm reading. The book is **PHP & MySQL: Novice to Ninja** from the author Kevin Yank and the reference is at page 135.

I did want to confirm because there is some stuff i read in this book which seem unusual to me and I think the better way to confirm would be to ask the community.

Comment: Where have you read that?

Comment: @MathieuImbert i updated my question to include that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a question of using links, it's a question of GET vs POST.

GET requests should be literally just that: to get stuff. It should not change anything on the server.

POST requests may change things, and should be used in this situation.

Comment: I've seen people referring to $_GET length instead of recommending usage of $_POST, are they wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what they might be referring to, but in general if you stick to the "GET is for getting stuff, POST is for changing it", you should be fine.

Comment: @Kolink just wondering your opinion, so you wouldn't have a list of users with links for delete (i.e. /user/42/delete) you would use a form Post?

Comment: Exactly. [This blog post](http://blog.mischel.com/2008/08/08/hey-you-deleted-my-files/) tells of just one reason why you shouldn't use GET for anything transformative.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are perfectly acceptable - they just send the info in a slightly different way.  What you do with the info when it arrives is up to you.

Comment: Not sure if they still exist, but with the old browser pre-fetch features (or search engine bots), `GET` / links can lead to unwanted results if you use it to do something like delete stuff.

Comment: You clearly have no experience as a webmaster, @splash21... If you did, you would not be advising this, trust me!

Comment: @Happyninja Where the bot is concerned, yes there should be. However, when you login, your browser is authenticated so if it decides to pre-fetch some pages from links, you might have a serious problem.

Comment: This thread is tagged as PHP - both are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: You clearly have no experience with PHP, @Kolink